# How to initialize std::vector<std::time_t> with n elements in constructor initializer list

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, time-t

I am trying to initialize vector in constructor initializer list like so:

```
Foo::Foo()
    : vec{42}
{
    //  ...
}
```

The vector is declared as:

```
std::vector<std::time_t> vec;
```

Problem is that `std::time_t` is numeric type also, so instead of creating vector with 42 elements as I would like, it creates one element with stored value '42'.

Question: is there a way to initialize such vector with size in constructor initializer list?

Comment: `: vec(42, time_t{})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When initialized with braced-init-list, the constructor of `std::vector` taking `std::initializer_list` is preferred; for `vec{42}` it would initialize `vec` as containing 1 element with value `42`.

You can apply parentheses initializer instead of braced-init-list (which is a C++11 feature).

```
Foo::Foo()
    : vec(42) // initialize vec as containing 42 default-initialized elements
{
    //  ...
}
```